# Uploading image with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf and Spring boot to upload an image to a database.
First steps I took were creating the upload page and controller method to get the MultipartFile(image) as byte array.

This is where I'm not getting the right byte array.

My code for the thymeleaf part:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <form action="#" th:action="url to the controller method" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="image">Upload image</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input id="image" type="file" name="image"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is my Spring boot controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "url to the controller method", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createImage(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image) {

    try {
        byte[] design = image.getBytes();

        System.out.println(design.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

My to string returns:

```
[B@4fe2fee8
```

This doesn't seem the right value, because when I convert the same image on the internet I get a long list of 0's and 1's.

Does someone know how to fix this? It seems like my multipart file doesn't contain the uploaded image.

My url in the action of the form seems right, because I can reach my Post method in the controller.

### Edit

Checking the MultipartFile in my controller with image.isEmpty() isn't true.

Comment: when you  run println on an array you wil print the object and not its contents. Did you debug and check what the array contains?

Comment: Don't bother about the strange value of what `toString` returns, the default implementation just returns something like <object class>@<hashcode> like what you see .

Answer (score 1):

toString doesn't print the content of your byte array. The java doc for Object.toString state the following:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.

That's exactly what is displayed. The array contains all you 0 and 1. You can easily write the content into a file and open it to see if it's the correct image.

```
Files.write(Paths.get("image.jpg"), image.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Arrays.stream(design).forEach(System.out::println)` to print the contents.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the image data is empty you could simply do this:

```
if (design.length == 0) {
  System.out.println("design is empty");
}
```